# new website is not loading theme css files in Magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, indexing

I have Magento 1.7.0.2 in domain A. I've created a new "website" under this same Magento installation. This "new website" has a different URL (B).

I configured the theme in Admin-panel and the new URL, then added the theme files through FTP, but when i access to domain B there's no css loaded. I enabled the Template Path Hints and i can see the path ponting to the corresponding new theme templates, but the css/js files (`skin/frontend/default/newtheme`) are not being loaded.

Under `/public_html/domainB.com`, I've added the index.php file, which loads the "new website" i created. This is the lines i modified:

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::run('marymcdonaldinc','website');
```

I don't think the problem is in index.php file, since it seems to be loading the "new website".

Answer (score 0):

Configure the following settings: `system->configuration->web`

- base URL : `http://example.com/magento/`
- Base Link URL : `http://example.com/magento/[B_folder name]/`

and the following settings for themes should display for B website: `system->configuration->Design` under Themes section

Set template & Default to [your theme].